# CONVMV and cyrillic filenames

Tags: linux, character-encoding

I am trying to convert filenames in russian zipfile to UTF-8 using convmv.
Original filename: "æ óá¡¿½∞¡δ¼ áα«¼áΓ«¼.jpg" (æ\ óá¡¿½∞¡δ¼\ áα«¼áΓ«¼.jpg with slashes)

This analyzer (https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) detected source encoding CP866 + displayed as CP437, and successfully decodes to desired С ванильным ароматом.jpg.

My question is, how can I set up convmv to decode it properly?
For `convmv -f cp866 -t utf-8 filename`, I get "already UTF-8", in --nosmart mode I get jibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single pass of `convmv` can only fix one level of wrong-ness at a time. Your particular file is more complicated. It was originally cp866, and it was at some point turned into UTF-8, but whatever did that conversion thought it was originally cp437 and so converted it wrong. To fix this, you need to run `convmv` twice:

```
convmv -f utf-8 -t cp437 --notest 'æ óá¡¿½∞¡δ¼ áα«¼áΓ«¼.jpg'
convmv -f cp866 -t utf-8 --notest $'\x91 \xa2\xa0\xad\xa8\xab\xec\xad\xeb\xac \xa0\xe0\xae\xac\xa0\xe2\xae\xac.jpg'
```

Note that I had to escape the name in the second command. If you're running this in bulk and/or don't want to deal with doing that, you can use something like `*.jpg`, or put all of the affected files in their own directory and use the `-r` option to `convmv`.